# The below SQL query takes around 6-7 min to execute and it will return ~ 5,833,135 rows, can any help me resolve it performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, psql, postgresql-9.5

The below SQL query takes around 6-7 min to execute and it will return ~ 5,833,135 rows, can any help me resolve it performance

### SQL

```
select
    min(aml.id) as id,
    aml.name as name,
    round(sum(aml.debit),2) as debit,
    round(sum(aml.credit),2) as credit,
    round(sum(aml.balance),2) as balance,
    aml.account_id as account_id,
    aml.move_id as move_id,
    aml.payment_id as payment_id,
    aml.statement_id as statement_id,
    aml.journal_id as journal_id,
    aml.date as date,
    aml.company_id as company_id,
    aml.invoice_id as invoice_id,
    aml.partner_id as partner_id,
    aml.company_currency_id as company_currency_id
from 
    account_move_line aml
    left join account_account acc on (acc.id = aml.account_id)
    left join account_move am on (am.id = aml.move_id)
    left join account_payment ap on (ap.id = aml.payment_id)
    left join account_bank_statement abs on (abs.id = aml.statement_id)
    left join account_journal aj on (aj.id = aml.journal_id)
    left join res_company comp on (comp.id = aml.company_id)
    left join account_invoice ai on (ai.id = aml.invoice_id)
    left join res_partner resp on (resp.id = aml.partner_id)
    left join res_currency rc on (rc.id = aml.company_currency_id)
group by
    aml.name,
    aml.debit,
    aml.credit,
    aml.balance,
    aml.account_id,
    aml.move_id,
    aml.payment_id,
    aml.statement_id,
    aml.journal_id,
    aml.date,
    aml.company_id,
    aml.invoice_id,
    aml.partner_id,
    aml.company_currency_id
```

Comment: 5 million rows, a lot of data to transfer. Cold or hot data?

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` tables you don't use anything from? Either remove them or `INNER JOIN`

Comment: **hot** account data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only selecting from one table, which is the first the series of `left join`s.

I wonder if this does what you want:

```
select min(aml.id) as id,
       aml.name as name,
       round(sum(aml.debit), 2) as debit,
       round(sum(aml.credit), 2) as credit,
       round(sum(aml.balance), 2) as balance,
       aml.account_id as account_id,
       aml.move_id as move_id,
       aml.payment_id as payment_id,
       aml.statement_id as statement_id,
       aml.journal_id as journal_id,
       aml.date as date,
       aml.company_id as company_id,
       aml.invoice_id as invoice_id,
       aml.partner_id as partner_id,
       aml.company_currency_id as company_currency_id
from account_move_line aml
group by aml.name, aml.debit, aml.credit, aml.balance,
         aml.account_id, aml.move_id, aml.payment_id,
         aml.statement_id, aml.journal_id, aml.date,
         aml.company_id,  aml.invoice_id, aml.partner_id,
         aml.company_currency_id;
```

You are then aggregating by so many columns that I wonder if aggregation is even necessary.

Comment: Still it takes 7 min

Comment: @Mack . . . At least you have a much simpler query to try to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can optimize with such a query.

In the order of effectivity:

- Put enough RAM in the machine that the whole database is cached.
- Set `work_mem` as big as you can for this query.
- If there are nested loop joins in the `EXPLAIN` output (unlikely), an index on the join column can help.